# Jquery scroll to Function call-in

Tags: jquery

I have a good piece of Scrollto code that allows me to smoothly animate to an anchor text.

```
$(function(){   
  function scrollToAnchor(aid){
    var aTag = $("a[name='"+ aid +"']");
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top},'slow');
  }

  $("#link").click(function() {
    scrollToAnchor('id123');
  });
}); 

<a id="link" href="#">click me to scroll to 123</a>

<a name="123" id="123"/>Anchor
```

http://jsfiddle.net/brandrally/rtspdL3u/

What I want to do is incorporate this into an ajax / jquery call in and I am just not getting it right.

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
  $("input[name$='item']").click(function() {
    var req = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({    
      cache: false,    
      type: "GET",
      url: "information.php?id=" + req,             
      dataType: "html",                  
      success: function(response){                    
        $("#responsecontainer").html(response); 
        //alert(response);
      }
    });

    scrollToAnchor('id123');

  });
});
```

Comment: is the code for `<a name="123" id="123"/>Anchor ` comes from ajax ??

Comment: Hi Atul, No. It's hardcoded on the page. It's the place I want it to go once the Ajax has done it's thing.

Comment: then call `scrollToAnchor('id123');` after `$("#responsecontainer").html(response);` inside success function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I was hard coding the destination after the call. I just removed the function aspect of the JS and just made straight out code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
  $("input[name$='item']").click(function() {
    var req = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({    
      cache: false,    
      type: "GET",
      url: "information.php?id=" + req,             
      dataType: "html",                  
      success: function(response){                    
        $("#responsecontainer").html(response); 
        //alert(response);
      }
    });

var aTag = $("a[name='"+ "id123" +"']");
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top},'slow');

  });
});
```